# Deleting RealmObject from RealmList

Tags: android, realm, realm-list

I have a `RealmObject` called, say `A` that is contained in a `RealmList` in `RealmObjects B and C`. `B` and `C` both have `many to many` relationships.

How do i remove the `A` from the `RealmList` in `B` but maintain it's relationship with `C` (i.e it should still be in `Cs RealmList`)?

In short, I need to know how to remove an object from a RealmList without affecting the other relationships the same object (without deleting it from Realm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like any list, really.

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    B b = realm.where(B.class).equalTo(BFields.ID, bId).findFirst();
    Iterator<A> iterator = b.getRealmList().iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        A a = iterator.next();
        if(a.getId().equals(idToDelete)) {
            iterator.remove(); // removes from realm list, but not from Realm
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

---

But I think if you redefine `hashCode()` and `equals()` to work based on primary key, then that ought to work reliably with `remove(Object object)` as well.